# Display running total using JavaScript on ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display the running total of Credit Amount column when the Select check box is check without reloading the page. In this case (see image below), the running total should print out 38. The Credit Amount column is editable, so the total amount should update accordingly based on the user inputs.
[image]

**What I have so far on my view**

```
<table class="gridtable">
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Submit Purchase Item Status Id</th>
            <th style="display:none;">Cart Order Id</th>
            <th>Customer Number</th>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th>Serial Number</th>
            <th>Charged Amount</th>
            <th>Credit Amount</th>
            <th>State Tax</th>
            <th>Credit Tax</th>
            <th>Billing Start Date</th>
            <th>Billing End Date</th>
            <th>Invoice Number</th>
            <th>Invoice Date</th>
            <th style="display:none;">Cart Billable Item Id</th>
            <th>Quality</th>
        </tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Selected)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].SubmitPurchaseItemStatusId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].SubmitPurchaseItemStatusId)
                </td>
                <td style="display:none;">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].CartOrderId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].Custnmbr)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].Custnmbr)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].Custname)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].Custname)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].Serltnum)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].Serltnum)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].ChargedAmt)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].ChargedAmt)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].CreditChargedAmt)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].CreditChargedAmt, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].StateTax)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].StateTax)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].CreditStateTax)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].CreditStateTax, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].BillStartDate)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].BillStartDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].BillEndDate)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].BillEndDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].Ordocnum)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].Ordocnum)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].Docdate)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].Docdate)
                </td>

                <td style="display:none;">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].CartBillableItemId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].Qty)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].Qty)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried so far and what specific problems do you have with your attempt?  See [ask].

Comment: Did you try writing a running total script on checking of boxes ?

Comment: How do i run the total script on checking of boxes? If you can point me to specific example, that would be great.

Comment: Also this is likely NOT an ASP question so please click [edit(https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58103416/edit), then the `[<>]` snippet editor and post RENDERED HTML and SCRIPT (and css if needed) but NO ASP

Comment: @micheal_uci : Replying to my running total comment above :

Below answer is perfect, otherwise you can check http://www.madirish.net/11 for reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mplungjan. Your answer works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the THs in THEAD and the rest of the rows in TBODY, give the TBODY an ID and then use

```js
function totalIt() {
  var total = 0;
  $("#someTotalContainer").html("0.00");
  $(this).closest("tbody").find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
    var val = $(this).closest("tr").find("input.amt").val(); // or use the class of the input field
    total += isNaN(val) || val == "" ? 0 : +val;
  });
  $("#someTotalContainer").html(total.toFixed(2));
}

$(function() {
  $("#tbd").on("change", "input[type=checkbox]", totalIt);
  totalIt()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="gridtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Charged Amount</th>
      <th>Credit Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbd">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="amt" value="19" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="amt" value="19" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
$<span id="someTotalContainer"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mplungjan. Your answer works perfectly.